# How to fix 'PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: getTest() parameter' error in PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I’m setting up the PHP Unit in my Laravel project, but I'm receiving Fatal Error in my first run. Can someone give a help?

I'm running in my Laravel Project, using Laravel 5.2.45, PHP 7.3.2 and PHPUnit 7.2.19. This is my first time trying to do some tests, but I always receive error, when I execute my test.

I expect when I run the phpunit receive the asset true, but I'm receiving the follow error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner::getTest() must be of the type string, object given, called in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php on line 180 and defined in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:59
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(180): PHPUnit\Runner\BaseTestRunner->getTest(Object(PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite), '', Array)
>
> 1 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(159): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run(Array, true)
>
> 2 /usr/bin/phpunit(34): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
>
> 3 {main}
>     thrown in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php on line 59

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hello. Yes, I find it yesterday. I have to stop this project to work in another. Yesterday I came back and the problem was I'm trying to execute in wrong directory. But now I have another problem when I try to execute a teste file with more than one function...

Answer (score -1):

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing#creating-and-running-tests)

You have to create your test by command

```
// Create a test in the Unit directory...
php artisan make:test UserTest --unit
```

If you already did so, check your `Tests\TestCase`, run `composer dump-autoload` and try again

Also you can use [Codeception](https://codeception.com/quickstart) with [Laravel5 module](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel5) for your tests

Comment: Thanks. The problem was I trying to execute phpunit in the wrong directory. Thanks for the help.